# How to split files in helm before creating configmap?

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-helm, helm3, configmap

As we all know, k8s configmap cannot be more than 1mb ([here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/#motivation)). I have a file which needs to be passed as configmap (not as volumemount). Below is the structure of the file.
file which will be in helm chart/file/rules.yaml

```
groups:
- name: alert-1
  rules:
  - alert: MimirIngesterUnhealthy
    annotations:
      message: {{printf "%f" $value }} unhealthy ingester(s).
    expr: | <expresseion>
for: 15m
    labels:
      severity: critical
- name: alert-2
  rules:
  - alert: MimirIngesterUnhealthy
    annotations:
      message: {{printf "%f" $value }} unhealthy ingester(s).
    expr: | <expresseion>
for: 15m
    labels:
      severity: critical
...
...
- name: alert-n
  rules:
  - alert: MimirIngesterUnhealthy
    annotations:
      message: {{printf "%f" $value }} unhealthy ingester(s).
    expr: | <expresseion>
for: 15m
    labels:
      severity: critical
```

Now, If I create a single configmap then the size exceeds 1mb and installation fails, So I am thinking to split this file into multiple configmaps, each configmap for one alert rule.
ex:

```
configmap-1--> will have details of alert1
configmap-2--> will have details of alert2
```

can we do it either using helm template or functions, I want to do it in helm only.

1. Increasing the limit on etcd is out of the question.

Comment: It's probably possible to `.Files.Get` the file in your Helm chart, parse it `fromYaml`, and split it up, or to use something like `substr` to break up the file into chunks without worrying about the format.  You would need to write actual code somewhere to reassemble the file, though, Kubernetes doesn't have any native way to do this.  Would it be easier to inject the configuration via some other path (copying it into an image, `kubectl cp` into a persistent volume)?

Comment: split will remove the separator,

Comment: checking the substr, but not sure how to read each element